# What is the time complexity of leaflet function onEachFeature function here

Tags: javascript, json, leaflet, time-complexity, geojson

What is the complexity of the leaflet function [`onEachFeature`](http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/) in general? is it the same as the complexity of a `for` loop when it comes to processing each key in a big geojson file?

Comment: Complexity with respect to what variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onEachFeature` is a user-defined function, and thus its algorithmical complexity cannot be known beforehand.

It does get called once per GeoJSON `Feature` on initialization of a `L.GeoJSON` instance, and whenever the `.addData()` method of a `L.GeoJSON` is called.

Also take into account that instantiating any `L.Circle`, `L.Polyline` or `L.Polygon` has a complexity of `O(n*log(n))`, where `n` is the number of points in the geometry, due to usage of a [Douglas-Peucker simplification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm).

Thus, complexity of adding features to a `L.GeoJSON` should be of a magnitude like

```
 O( m * (n*log(n) + f ) )
```

Where `m` is the number of features, `n` is the number of points/vertices per feature, and `f` is the complexity of the user-defined `onEachFeature` function.